# Jquery popup with single enabled datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog with a few controls and datetimepicker. When I disable all component, except datetimepicker  a datetimepicker select dialog appears. He get focus and select date triggers. How can I fix this problem? I want just to show text box with date.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make Id field readonly and add ui-state-disabled class so your field will have the same style as disabled field.

```
$(selector).addClass('ui-state-disabled').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

So when you open your dialog focus will be set on Id field.

Answer (score 1):

Make it open only on button click(not on focus like the default settings.)

```
$(".selector").datepicker( "option", "showOn", 'button' );
```

Comment: It`s work, but this solution broke my mark up (. I have two datetime picker, and it looks not good - one of them disabled and without button, another with button. But though, thank you.

Comment: @IvanKorytin. So give them two different classes\ids.

Comment: I talk about main idea, not the bugs with html and css.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by:

***Eg:***

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: I don`t want to disable it. I want to leave it enabled. But when I did that - select date dialog appears. It`s wrong. I need just textbox without active windows on popup open.

Comment: @IvanKorytin If you don't want the date dialog appear, what is the difference between disable it and enable it but let the dialog not show.

Comment: It`s not clear for me. I tried your code, but dialog steel show. Could you fill me in?